# iterate over an array on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to print the next item in array when ever I click the button. It just prints 2. I want it to print 2, then I click the button, it should print 3, and click and print 4 and so on

this is the code:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Sample Question</p>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function nextQuestion() {
            var questionArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
            var arrayLength = questionArray.length;

            for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                $('#results').html(i);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input type='button' onClick='nextQuestion();' id='nextquestion' value='Next' />
</body>
```

Comment: Can u make jsfiddle to show ur problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<h1>Sample Question</h1>
<input type='button' id='nextquestion' value='Next' />
<div id="results"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var questionStack = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];

$('#nextquestion').click(function() {
    $('#results').html(questionStack.pop());    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2G64/)**

Full code:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sample Question</h1>
    <input type='button' id='nextquestion' value='Next' />
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var questionStack = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];    
            $('#nextquestion').click(function() {
                 $('#results').html(questionStack.pop());    
            });
        });
    </script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you're printing right now has nothing to do with your array, but has to do with i. No need to use a for loop here either. Basically you need to keep track of the indice, then increment that by one each time your function is ran. Something like this should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var counter = 0;
   var questionArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    function nextQuestion() {
         $('#results').html(questionArray[counter]);
         counter++
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G57ra/)**

See this,

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Sample Question</p>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;

    function nextQuestion() {
        var questionArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        var arrayLength = questionArray.length;


        if (count == arrayLength) {
            count = 0;
        }
        $('#results').html(questionArray[count]);
        count++;

    }
    </script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way using the `module pattern`

```
var nextQuestion = (function() {
    var questionArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        $('#results').html(questionArray[i%questionArray.length]);
        i++;
    }
})();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKcfr/)